# np.piecewise does not work with three conditions

Tags: python, numpy, piecewise

i am very new to python and need to define a piecewise funtion, however, as soon as i specify more than two conditions i am greeted with "ValueError: function list and condition list must be the same".

For example, the very basic test function

```
def test(r):
    r1=1.8
    return np.piecewise(r, [(r<r1), (r==r1), (r>r1)], [0, 1, 2])
```

produces this error, whereas a function with only two conditions

```
def test(r):
    r1=1.8
    return np.piecewise(r, [(r<r1), (r>r1)], [0, 2])
```

works flawlessly. I circumvented my problem by using np.select, however, i am curious as to what my mistake is and how to resolve it. I am not sure if this of interest, but the variable "r" used in the function is going to be a scalar value, not a list or array or something complicated.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve my problem?

Comment: your first example works fine for me. Please give more details about the error, and fix indentation

Comment: What version is your `numpy`? I don't see anything in the `piecewise` code that would produce this error.  You may need to show the full error message.

Answer (score 3):

you are passing a list to the function but you should pass a numpy array:

```
r1 = 1.8
r = numpy.arange(0, 3, 0.2)
print numpy.piecewise(r, [(r<r1), (r==r1), (r>r1)], [0, 1, 2])
# prints:
# array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2., 2.,  2.])
```

but adding

```
r = list(r)
print numpy.piecewise(r, [(r<r1), (r==r1), (r>r1)], [0, 1, 2])
```

gives the error you mention.

Comment: The `list(r)` produces the error in `(r<r1)`, (`unorderable types`), before even entering `piecewise`.  The OP claims to have problems with scalar `r`, not a list.

Comment: from the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html), `piecewise` requires `r` to be a `ndarray` unlike, say, `numpy.dot(a,b)`, which requires `a` and `b` to be `array_like`. So while it is true that `(r<r1)` will not work if `r` is a `list`, the error is produced before that, when passing a `list` to `piecewise`. I checked that the error produced by the last block is indeed the one the OP mentions.

Comment: In which version of numpy?